# Translating CoffeeScript question mark syntax into Javascript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have a CoffeeScript snippet that uses the Question mark operator. I need to translate into Javascript syntax. The snippet is like the following.

```
closeItem: (item) ->
    item.close() if item?.close and not item.isClosed
```

I tried to run into CoffeeScript site and the result is the following.

```
({
  closeItem: function(item) {
    if ((item != null ? item.close : void 0) && !item.isClosed) {
      return item.close();
    }
  }
});
```

Is this correct? Based on my knowledge (I'm new both on Javascript and CoffeeScript) I would translate as

```
closeItem: function(item) {
    if(item && item.close && !item.isClosed) item.close();
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: `?:;` is a `if` statement in itself 

    `if(true){a++;}else{a--;}`

is equal to

    `true?a++:a--;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your translation is good, although you might want to return the return value of `item.close()` (as that's what the CoffeeScript version does). CoffeeScript's translation is probably more general-purpose (for instance, it would handle `a?.foo` if `a` were the number `0`). If you know `item` is an object, your version is fine.

Comment: CoffeeScript is handling the edge case when item is falsey (like `false` or ''). It's distinguishing existence vs truthiness.

Comment: @PeterLyons: Right (actually I just edited in a similar observation, in my case the number `0`). It's not needed in the OP's code, but it's more general-purpose.

Comment: Sorry for the question, but does `if(item)` already check for falsy values in javascript, so also for `0` and `''` values?

Comment: And finally, what `void 0` supposed to be? Thanks

Comment: @flexaddicted: *"but does if(item) already check for falsy values in javascript"* Yes. `if (item)` will follow the branch if `item` is *truthy*. A *truthy* value is a value that isn't *falsey*. The *falsey* values are: `undefined`, `null`, `0`, `""`, `NaN`, and of course, `false`. *"what void 0 supposed to be"* The `void` operator is very strange: It evaluates its operand, but the result of the operation is always `undefined`. So `void 0` is a way to write `undefined` but which isn't susceptible to someone giving a different value to the `undefined` symbol (which can be done in loose mode).

Comment: So, why did you write *for instance, it would handle `a?.foo` if a were the number `0`*? Thank you for your support.

Comment: @flexaddicted: Your version would fail: `a = 0; if (a && a.toString) { /* this doesn't happen */ }` CoffeeScript's would work, because it's not filtering out *all* falsey values, only `undefined` and `null` (the expression `x != null` will be false if `x` is `null` or `x` is `undefined`, but true if `x` is `0` [or `""`, or...]).

Comment: Thank you. Maybe a stupid question, but why will the expression `x != null` be false if `x` is `undefined`? Any coercion under the hood?

Comment: @flexaddicted: Yes, exactly. The `==` operator does type coercion, and `null` is `==` to `undefined` (and `"0" == 0`). `undefined` is the only thing (other than itself) that `null` is `==` to, so even though the coercion rules in general are very complex and it's frequently best to avoid implicit coercion by using `===` and `!==` instead, `x != null` is a common idiom for testing that `x` is not `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: I really appreciated your support. Have a nice weekend.